# display suite code - set token value of color field module as php variable an convert to rgb

Tags: tokens, display-suite

```
$hex = "[node:field-ref-participants-category:field_color]";
print $hex;
list($r, $g, $b) = sscanf($hex, "#%02x%02x%02x");
echo "rgba($r,$g,$b,.9)";
```

Why does $hex printed correctly, but doenst work in the sscanf-function? when I set $hex = "#000000" manually instead of the token replacement is converts correctly...

is there another way to set the $hex-variable. the color comes from a reference term with a colorfield in it.